# Convert string color value to Brush in VB.Net Windows

Tags: color-conversion

How to convert a **html color value** like "**#FFE5E5E5**" to system.windows.media.brush in a single line statement?

Answer (score 0):

Following single line **VB.Net** statement converts a HTML color value to Brush, that can be used for programmatic assignment of value to HTML objects.

**Statement**

```
Fill = CType(New System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FFE5E5E5"), Brush)
```

**Dependency**

1. Imports `System.Windows.Media`